# Mixing void_t and variadic templates?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, sfinae, void-t

Consider the following code:

```
template <class F, class... Args, class = std::void_t<>>
struct is_invokable
: std::false_type {};
template <class F, class... Args>
struct is_invokable<F, Args..., std::void_t<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>>>
: std::true_type {};
```

The goal is to have a trait that is able to tell whether a callable of type `F` is invokable with arguments of type `Args...`.

However, it fails to compile because:

```
error: parameter pack 'Args' must be at the end of the template parameter list
```

What is the (elegant) way to do this in C++17?

Comment: Well, where else other than the end can you put `void`? Put it there.

Comment: Huh. I didn’t realize that types required the pack to be in the final position. Functions don’t, if you give default arguments or they can be deduced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
namespace details {
  template <class F, class, class... Args>
  struct is_invokable : std::false_type {};
  template <class F, class... Args>
  struct is_invokable<F, std::void_t<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>>, Args...>
  : std::true_type {};
}
template <class F, class... Args>
using is_invokable=typename ::details::is_invokable<F, void, Args...>::type;
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose an helper `struct` (`is_invokable_h`) and the use of `std::tuple` to wrap the `Args...`

Something like

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename, typename, typename = void>
struct is_invokable_h : std::false_type
 {};

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
struct is_invokable_h<F, std::tuple<Args...>,
                      std::void_t<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>>>
   : std::true_type
 {};

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
struct is_invokable : is_invokable_h<F, std::tuple<Args...>>
 {};

int foo (int)
 { return 0; }

int main()
 {
   static_assert( true  == is_invokable<decltype(foo), int>{} );
   static_assert( false == is_invokable<decltype(foo), int, int>{} );
 }
```

Comment: Or [std::is_invocable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) introduced by C++17.

Comment: You're right: or `std::is_invocable`. But was my intention show a possible way to bypass the problem of the default template type after a template variadic list.